# Random File Access Issues IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have two methods to retrieve images on an ASP.NET MVC website. If I search for the images on disk using File Explorer, the image are there, but my log file shows many errors saying that each image does not exists.

Sometimes it works without issues but others, my application could not find the image. If I restart my IIS site or restart the computer, it works without any issues, but it has a random behaviour that I must resolve.

The two paths where the images are located are:

```
"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test_Application\Content\Images" (Inside site public dir)
"C:\Test_Application\images" (Configured on IIS as a virtual directory)
```

This is a Windows 10 Pro device, running IIS and the application pool that is running the site has a windows account with administrative rights as identity because I need to connect to a SQL Server LocalDb.

The function that writes the message to log is:

```
private bool Func_GetImages(RecordModel record)
{
    bool bResult = false;
    List<string> imagesFound = new List<string>();
    string sImageMaskName = string.Empty;
    string sAbsoluteImgPath = string.Empty;
    string sSourceImgPath = string.Empty; //Path to img directory with year, month and day.
    string sTargetImgPath = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        Config.LogHelper.Func_WriteEventInLogFile(DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime(), enum_EventTypes.Debug, "Func_GetImages", "Get Images: ",
        string.Format("Get images for record with GUID: {0}; Image Mask Name: {1}; Times for Images: {2}", record.GUID, record.imageMaskName,
        record.TimeBetweenColorImages));

        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            sAbsoluteImgPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Config.sImgDirectory);
            sTargetImgPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/Processed");
        }
        else
        {
            sAbsoluteImgPath = string.Format("{0}/", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
            sTargetImgPath = string.Format("{0}/", "~/Content/Images/Processed");
        }

        sSourceImgPath = Path.Combine(sAbsoluteImgPath, record.DetectionDatetime.Year.ToString(), record.DetectionDatetime.Month.ToString("D2"), record.DetectionDatetime.Day.ToString("D2"));
        Config.LogHelper.Func_WriteEventInLogFile(DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime(), enum_EventTypes.Debug, "Func_GetImages", "Get Images: ",
        string.Format("Path to search for files: {0}", sSourceImgPath));

        sImageMaskName = record.imageMaskName;

        if (!Directory.Exists(sSourceImgPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(sSourceImgPath);
        }

        //Try to get files with this search pattern
        imagesFound = Directory.GetFiles(sSourceImgPath, string.Format("{0}*", sImageMaskName)).ToList();

        if (imagesFound.Count > 0)
        {
            Config.LogHelper.Func_WriteEventInLogFile(DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime(), enum_EventTypes.Debug, "Func_GetImages", "Get Images: Ok",
            string.Format("Number of images for record with GUID: {0} is {1}", record.GUID, imagesFound.Count.ToString()));

            //Create new image name
            DateTime dateCapture = record.DetectionDatetime;
            string sImageName = record.imageMaskName;

            //Check if day directory exists. If not, create it
            Func_CheckOrCreateImageDirectory(dateCapture);

            string sBaseDirectory = Path.Combine(sTargetImgPath, dateCapture.Year.ToString(), dateCapture.Month.ToString("D2"), dateCapture.Day.ToString("D2"));

            //Rename, add image header and copy blackWhiteImages
            Func_ProcessImages(sBaseDirectory, sImageMaskName, sImageName, detection.numPicturesColor, enum_ImagesType.COLOR, detection); 

        }
        else
        {
            Config.LogHelper.Func_WriteEventInLogFile(DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime(), enum_EventTypes.Error, "Func_GetImages", "Get Images: Ko",
            string.Format("No images found for record with GUID: {0} and Image Mask Name: {1}", record.GUID, sImageMaskName));
        }

        bResult = true;
    }
    catch (Exception exception1)
    {
        Config.LogHelper.Func_WriteEventInLogFile(DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime(), enum_EventTypes.Error, new StackTrace(exception1).GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name, "GeneralException",
        "Source = " + exception1.Source.Replace("'", "''") + ", Message = " + exception1.Message.Replace("'", "''"));
    }

    return bResult;
}
```

The log message written when the problem occurs is on the else sentence when I check if "imagesFound.Count > 0".

This is the error message that appears sometimes:

> No images found for record with GUID: 8689ffcd-46d2-4a25-ab57-edce11e45977 and Image Mask Name: 002475-20190702_070949_326

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How are the files getting written to the folder?  Are you sure there's not a race condition involved?  You should maybe try adding some additional logging to your else condition to get more details about what happens when it finds no images.   On a side note, you should examine your need for Admin rights.   That's a huge security risk to run like that.

Comment: The files are stored by two external applications. When I search manually for the files, they are there. If we make some test restarting IIS server, the issue appears once each 10 tries. I think that the solution you offer, is for contexts where the issues happen always. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some tests and it was caused by this code:

```
if (HttpContext.Current != null)
{
    sAbsoluteImgPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Config.sImgDirectory);
    sTargetImgPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/Processed");
}
else
{
    sAbsoluteImgPath = string.Format("{0}/", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
    sTargetImgPath = string.Format("{0}/", "~/Content/Images/Processed");
}
```

I solved it setting the value of "sImgDirectory" in "Web.config" to the project root dir and making the paths relative to this path stored on a static variable.